# задача на сортировку строки

Tags: javascript

Нашел интересную задачку, но решение до конца не смог довести.Написать функцию, которая на вход получает строку, которая содержит числа (пример: "56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90"). Необходимо отсортировать, используя "вес" каждого числа. "Вес" будет считаться как сумма всех цифр числа (вес 56 = 5 + 6;). Если вес у чисел одинаковый (например 180 (вес 9) и 90 (вес 9)), то их необходимо сравнить как строки. Результатом должна возвращаться строка, которая состоит из отсортированных чисел.
Вот что я налопатил

```
function b(str) {
    var sorter = str.split(' ');var arr;
    sorter.sort(function(a,b) {
        for(var i = 0;i<sorter.length;i++) {
            arr = sorter[i].split('').reduce(function(a,b){a=+a;b=+b;return a+b});

        }
        console.log(sorter)
    })
}
b('103 123 4444 99 2000')
```

Comment: `sorter[i].split('').reduce(function(a,b){a=+a;b=+b;return a+b})` что это по вашему мнение должно делать

Comment: аааа, это вы там цифры складываете в числе

Comment: сортировка должна возвращать число, а у вас ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) принимает в качестве аргумента callback-функцию, которая должна сравнивать два значения и возвращать отрицательное/положительное число или 0 в зависимости от результата. Нужно с осторожностью подходить к любой другой логике, описываемой внутри этой функции.
Например, цикл в вашем случае абсолютно не нужен - он будет запускаться при каждом вызове callback-функции и выполнять одну и ту же работу.

Правильней будет вынести логику в функцию-helper, вызываемую только для сравниваемых значений.

Кроме того, обратите внимание на метод [compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator/compare) объекта [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator). Именно этот метод стоит использовать для сортировки строк, если это строки, состоящие из цифр (или символов латинского алфавита).

```js
function strSum(s) {
    return s.split("").reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b))
}

function sort(s) {
    return s
        .split(" ")
        .sort((a, b) => {
            const a1 = strSum(a)
            const b1 = strSum(b)

            return a1 !== b1
                ? a1 - b1
                : new Intl.Collator().compare(a, b)
        })
        .join(" ")
}

console.log(sort('102 2000 10 4 51 302'));
console.log(sort('103 123 4444 99 2000'));
console.log(sort('11 31 56 4'));
```

Comment: `,0` - не нужен, вместо `+=` -> `+`. _Если вес у чисел одинаковый (например 180 (вес 9) и 90 (вес 9)), то их необходимо **сравнить как строки**._

Comment: @Grundy на счет строки, да, не доглядел, на счет нуля, просто привык всегда прописывать значение начальное, а `+=` или `+` вроде как большой роли не играет